# Submit data in a textbox from a while loop to database

Tags: php, mysql

I need to enter scores for all subjects offered by all students in a class simultaneously. So I retrieved the students ID, retrieved the list of subjects being offered by the students, and placed a textbox under each subject.

Now, I want to submit the score in the database as well as the subject name and the student ID, but the score is not storing, just the subject name and the student ID.

Here is my code:

```
<form method="post">
  <?php
    include "includes/dbcon.php";
    $subject_name ="";
    echo "<table border='1'><thead><tr><td>Students Name</td>";
    $query_subjects = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM junior_subjects ORDER BY subject_name ASC");
    while ($row_subject=mysqli_fetch_array($query_subjects))
    {
      $subject_name .= $row_subject['subject_name'];
      echo "<td>".$row_subject['subject_name']."</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr></thead>";
    $query_students = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM students WHERE class_cat='Junior'");
    while ($row_students=mysqli_fetch_array($query_students))
    {
      $student_id = $row_students['student_id'];
      echo "<tr><td>".$row_students['student_id']."</td>";
      $query_subjects2 = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM junior_subjects ORDER BY subject_name ASC");
      while ($row_subject2 =mysqli_fetch_array($query_subjects2))
      {
        $subject_name2 =$row_subject2['subject_name'];
        echo "<td>
                <input type='text' hidden name='$subject_name2'>
                <input type='text' size='4' name='$subject_name2'>
              </td>";
        /////
        if (isset($_POST['submit']))
        {
          $score = $_POST[$subject_name2];
          mysqli_query($link,"INSERT INTO score_sheet(student_id,subject_name,score) VALUES('$student_id','$subject_name2','$score') ");
        }
      }
    }   
  ?>
  <input type='submit' name='submit'>
</form>
```

Comment: Not storing means ? What error you got ?

Comment: By not storing, I meant it was not saving the data in the databse. As for error, I didn't get any error.

Comment: Can you tell what is the output now ? Just replace you if with this one https://eval.in/384688

Comment: It's saying undefined index "the subject name"

Comment: Ok, So, You're not supplying anything to `subject_name`. Why don't you supply to it ?

Comment: I am supplying something...I enter values in the textbox, but it's still showing that

Comment: Is the name of the textbox is `subject_name` and it doesn't have `disabled` tag inside it ?

Comment: No it doesn't. Now it's displaying 111(continuously) but still not saving in the database

Comment: Inside your `if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{` Can you do this ? `echo "this is the value '.$_POST[$subject_name2];` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have the input `score` as array and make a foreach loop to insert the query.

You should have the input field like this

And do a foreach loop like this

```
    $score = $_POST['score'];
    foreach ($score as $key) 
    {
    $query = "INSERT INTO score_sheet(student_id,subject_name,score) VALUES('$student_id','$subject_name2','$key') ";   
    $query = mysqli_query($link,$query);    
    }
```

**Note :**

You should not have have two forms inside it.

I have made an [eval](https://eval.in/384711) for you

**Warning :**

It is not at all a good practise to have such a bulk entry.